# macOS Catalina :repo error: Exited sync due to fetch errors

Tags: android, android-source

OS : macOS Catalina 10.15.2
it is failed with "error: Exited sync due to fetch errors"
why is that,anyone know why?

```
repo version v1.13.8
       (from https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo)
repo launcher version 1.26
       (from /Users/louiswong/bin/repo)
       (currently at 1.13.8)
repo User-Agent git-repo/1.13.8 (Darwin) git/2.23.0 Python/2.7.16
git 2.23.0
git User-Agent git/2.23.0 (Darwin) git-repo/1.13.8
Python 2.7.16 (default, Nov  9 2019, 05:55:08) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.32.4) (-macos10.15-objc-s
```

```
louiswong@LouisWongs-MBP:/Volumes/SamsungT5/a6$ repo sync -j6 -f

....
....
....

Fetching projects: 100% (528/528), done.

error: Exited sync due to gc errors
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved. change operating system to macOS Catalina 10.14.6